# What does it mean that Koin does not support Lazy API as of Jetpack Compose 1.1+?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, koin

Just exploring Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile and came across `Koin` for dependency injection. At the end of the documentation on [Injecting in Jetpack Compose and Android](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-compose/compose) it says

> DANGER
> Lazy API is not supported with updates of jetpack Compose 1.1+

What does this mean practically? What's the lazy API?

Comment: Following in case someone can answer.

Comment: the lazy API is not supported in Jetpack Compose 1.1+. This means that if you are using the lazy API in your code, you will need to update your code to use the new injection methods. For example, instead of using the inject() function, you will need to use the get() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically, it means you shouldn't inject `ViewModels` in `Compose` like this:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposableScreen() {
    val viewModel by viewModel<MyViewModel>()
}
```

and you should do like this:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposableScreen() {
    val viewModel = getViewModel<MyViewModel>()
}
```

or like this to be more idiomatic with the functional aspects of `Compose`:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposableScreen(vm : MyViewModel = koinViewModel()) {

}
```

The lazy API mentioned in this footnote is the [property delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#lazy-properties) way of getting a `ViewModel` instance, that is no longer supported by `Compose` 1.1+ and crashes composables that try to use it internally as explained [here](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/1358#issuecomment-1237869516) by a `Koin` maintainer.

I'd say this is related to `Compose` internal implementation and possible side effects of using these lazy initializations during all the recompositions, so it is avoided altogether in any composable.

Comment: thank you, accepted as final answer. all answers here are correct, but this was the fastest one to grasp for me.

Answer (score 1):

Join developers have already made a statement on this issue.

> We need to deprecate ViewModel Lazy API. With the last realignment
> with Android ViewModel API 2.4.0, Jetpack Compose 1.1 breaks while
> trying to use Lazy API. The other thing is, you don't need Lazy API in
> Compose (don't use the by delegate style). Just use getViewModel (
> alias koinViewModel )  function to resolve your ViewModel instances.

[Link](https://blog.kotzilla.io/koin-3-2-2-updates/)

There are good examples for practical use.

[Link](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/compose/)